# AVCapture iOS — user experience when capturing at lower frame rates

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, frame-rate

I am working with some computer vision algorithms that require me to work on lower frame rates ~ sometimes even 7-10 fps.

The issue is that I don't want the user to have a poor experience when using the app but I still want to process at a lower frame rate. Is there a builtin API to do this?

I don't have to go into the delegate method and manually drop frames myself and work on the ones that are required.

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hard / nearly impossible to drop frames manually without screwing your video but you can configure your encoder like this

```
// in you initialisation code
NSError *err;
AVCaptureDevice* dev = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[dev lockForConfiguration:&err];
[self configureCameraForFrameRate:dev frameRate:10];
[dev unlockForConfiguration];
 - (void)configureCameraForFrameRate:(AVCaptureDevice *)device frameRate:(NSInteger)rate;
{
    AVCaptureDeviceFormat *bestFormat = nil;
    AVFrameRateRange *bestFrameRateRange = nil;
    for ( AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format in [device formats] ) {
        for ( AVFrameRateRange *range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges ) {
            if ( range.maxFrameRate > bestFrameRateRange.maxFrameRate ) {
                bestFormat = format;
                bestFrameRateRange = range;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( bestFormat ) {
        device.activeFormat = bestFormat;
        CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, rate);
        device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = time;
        //NSLog(@"%d %lld",bestFrameRateRange.minFrameDuration.timescale, bestFrameRateRange.minFrameDuration.value);
        device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = time;
    }
}
```

Not sure it's the best way to achieve this but ... ^^'

Comment: Well this is pretty much what I have but this doesn't solve the issue. This still shows the user that he is capturing at 10fps and not 30fps. What I need is to create an illusion that the user captures at 30fps even if the frames are processed at 7fps.

Comment: Maybe you want to read the question and talk properly. Either will work.

Comment: @p0lAris the Q says 7-10fps, your comment is "This still shows the user that he is capturing at 10fps and not 30fps", wut? You can skip frames or limit framerate, either will work.